# How to programatically add and remove tiles?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to add tiles for another program, programatically in Windows Phone 8?

It does not necessarily have to be the same app.

If possible, how can one go about doing this from another program?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [ShellTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). A good guide covering the basics of the subject is available [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-add-and-remove-secondary-tiles-in-windows-phone-apps). With Windows Phone 8 in the game, you have a couple more options - all covered in the official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question as I realized it was not clear enough. But thanks though.